# Regex to find string without curly braces but "\{", "\}" is allowed

Tags: regex

I have a regex to find string without curly braces **"([^\{\}]+)"**. So that it can extract "cde" from follwing string:

**"ab{cde}f"**

Now I need to escape "{" with "\{" and "}" with "\}".

So if my original string is **"ab{cd\{e\}}f"** then I need to extract **"cd{e}"** or **"cd\{e\}"** (I can remove "\" later).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `\\{`? Does a backslash escape the escaping backslash? If so, you're getting into territory where a simply regex is not adequate, but you should rather try to write an actual parser.

Comment: Yes that's true backslash escape the escaping backslash "\\" => "\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
([^{}\\]|\\{|\\})+
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I just needed to enclose this in one more group i.e. (([^{}\\]|\\{|\\})+)

Answer (score 2):

Note that any regex special characters are effectively escaped by putting them inside a range (i.e. square brackets).  So:

- [.] matches a literal period.
- [[] matches a left square bracket.
- [a] matches the letter a.
- [{] matches a left curly brace.

So:

```
$ echo "ab{cde}f" | sed -r 's/[^{]*[{](.+)}.*/\1/'
cde
$ echo "ab{c\{d\}e}f" | sed -r 's/[^{]*[{](.+)}.*/\1/'
c\{d\}e
```

Or:

```
$ echo "ab{cde}f" | sed 's/[^{]*{//;s/}[^}]*$//'
cde
$ echo "ab{c\{d\}e}f" | sed 's/[^{]*{//;s/}[^}]*$//'
c\{d\}e
```

Or even:

```
$ php -r '$s="ab{cde}f"; print preg_replace("/[^{]*[{](.+)}.*", "$1", $s) . "\n";'
cde
$ php -r '$s="ab{c\{d\}e}f"; print preg_replace("/[^{]*[{](.+)}.*/", "$1", $s) . "\n";'
c\{d\}e
```

Obviously, this does not handle escaped backslashes.  :-)

Comment: Actually, you almost handle escaped backslashes with your second option, using traditional sed to strip off the outer edges of the string.  One small edit: `echo "ab{c\\{d\\}e}f" | sed 's/[^{]*{//;s/}[^}]*$//'` returns **`c\\{d\\}e`**

Answer (score 2):

To allow escapes inside your braces you can use:

```
{((?:[^\\{}]+|\\.)*)}
```

[Perl example](http://ideone.com/MNSjN):

```
my $str = "ab{cd\\{e\\}} also foo{ad\\}ok\\{a\\{d}";
print "$str\n";
print join ', ', $str =~ /{((?:[^\\{}]+|\\.)*)}/g;
```

Output:

```
ab{cd\{e\}} also foo{ad\}ok\{a\{d}
cd\{e\}, ad\}ok\{a\{d
```

Answer (score 0):

`\{(.+)\}` would extract everything between the first and last curly bracket

Comment: I have string with multiple curly brackets. I need to extract each group of chars without curly braces separately (but if it is escaped with "\" then it is allowed).

Comment: You can just match the regex till no results are returned